# typescript how to copy only properties and methods from interface to a new object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know that in javascript I can copy the fields from an object to another object using Object.assign().

However, what I want to do is grab only the properties here in this interface:

```
export interface SizeOption {
    width: number;
    height: number;
    unit: SizeUnit;
    dpi?: number;
}
```

using assign doesn't help because I have getters and setters I need to grab not just the backing fields.

Object.create() grabs both fields and methods, but I would prefer to only grab stuff from the interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript interfaces only exist at compile time. You can't use them at runtime, you have to manually specify the properties to copy there:

```js
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
    const result = {};
    for(const key of keys) result[key] = obj[key];
    return result;
}

const result = pick(sizeOption, "weight", "height", "unit");
```

Comment: Do you mind pointing them out? (I'm currently afk, so I can't really test)

Comment: Well, if typescript supported some compile-time construct (I don't know if it does), it could at least technically provide a list of strings of the fields that could then be used run-time.. Like `const destination = { ...source:SizeOption }` or whatnot

Comment: I use the playground to test, with a dev keyboard works almost decent on android ...

Comment: oh that makes sense. but that makes typescript's get set method support pretty poor. is there a good way to copy all getters and setters?

i guess I really do have to implement a deep clone method. I really just wanted to grab 4 fields and the getters/setters for them though.

Comment: This is what I would use: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/AQMwrgdgxgLglgewsADnKBrAPAFQDTACSwApgB4wkQAmAzsBiQJ4IjA4B8AFAgEYBWALnYEAdOMZNawwgG0AugEphABXTZ8RDsADeAKGCHgUJLRjAATiVpgANuYC8ugL7AAhvTWZcBQhwDcBkYgCBZcJhBmDMzArNFSipbWdjCykvLATnz8aczygUZJMGAWyFY29gXAznpBEVHlKZmo6ly0cABeJADyKPBIBABEAO4kcADmABYwg0OTY1MzQ5BwM4r+QA

Comment: I'm so disappointed. in C# this is so easy to do. but I guess I can't expect typescript to have the same level of control.

Comment: Maybe you are just thinking too much in C#. You need a paradigm shift :)

Comment: If you're coming from C#, why don't you use a `class` ? By using `new` you get your `deep clone` including getters and setters.

Comment: I assume this holds true the same for trying to implement an abstract class as well.  just thought I'd ask

Comment: the interface is tied to a lot of stuff, I wanted to keep the implementation in my class (quite a large class of 500+ lines related to size calculations) separate from other parts of the program that just need that interface and were already coded against it earlier.

Originally the file was 1000+ lines, so I have been trying to refactor things to get it more organized. however, I can't say I like hard coding the 4 strings that I'm pulling during my shallow copy. I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong

Comment: to be specific, I have a backing string that is used as both a string and as a number, throughout the app it is used mostly as a number, so that is what the interface defines. 

my two options seem to basically be use "pick" and select the properties I want from the class, or deep clone the object and have a lot of extra properties. I guess deep cloning is the correct choice then probably

Answer (score 3):

You can extract only the properties that you want from a more generic data object by using destructuring:

```
interface SizeOption {
    width: number
    height: number
    dpi?: number
}

interface JSONData {
    colors?:string
    width:number
    height:number
    dpi?:number
    title:string
    source:string
}

// data from json has some unwanted properties
const data : JSONData = {
    colors:"black",
    height:300,
    title:"help",
    source:"img.jpg",
    dpi:140,
    width:400
}

// get only width height dpi from json
const {width, height, dpi} = data

// create sizeoption object
const size:SizeOption = {width, height, dpi}

console.log(size)
```

BTW your use case is not entirely clear. If you want a `deep clone`, why not use a `class` ?